# Isabel 6 (banking) ERROR: "THE PAGE CANNOT BE DISPLAYED" OR "THE PAGE CANNOT BE FOUND"

Tags: internet-explorer

After installation of Isabel 6 Security Tools, cannot login to the Isabel 6 page.

error is

ERROR: "THE PAGE CANNOT BE DISPLAYED" OR "THE PAGE CANNOT BE FOUND"
(SSL and TLS  error).

anyone has an idea?

Comment: Have you tried their customer support? https://www.isabel.eu/en/forbusiness/support6/isabel6.html

Comment: I managed to login by disabling tsl / tls as advised by their service desl, but the connection is not secure anymore. ... any idea how to get around this?

Comment: https://www.isabel.eu/en/forbusiness/support6/websupport/direct.html?id=29542

Comment: Did you follow steps 5 and 6?

Comment: Step 5 check, step 6 not yet, I have to reach the user first...